# External HD has disappeared from Finder

Tags: finder, external-disk

I believe I created this problem. When I plugged my External HD in last week I accidentally dragged the Ext HD onto the desktop. It then disappeared from view in finder and there is no shortcut on the desktop or anywhere that I can find on my computer.

It does however show up in disk utility and when I unplug it, I receive the "inproperly ejected disk" message.

Does anyone know how I can make the Ext HD accessible again?

Comment: Is it broken? Or is it visible on another computer,

Comment: Use Disk Utility

Comment: I think he just hid the drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have only removed the visibility on your desktop.

- Go to Finder (The smiling blue man in your Dock in the lower part of your screen)
- Then press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> or go to Finder (menubar) and choose 'Preferences'
- Now choose 'General'
- Tick the checkbox that says "External Drives"

You can do the same for the Finder Sidebar

- Within the Finder Preferences choose 'Sidebar'
- Tick the checkboxes in the Devises section of the devices you want to see

Somewhere within the evolution of Finder they added this option, I am almost certain is wasn't added yet in OS 6 ;) With this feature they created a cleaner desktop and some confusion, I must admit.

Another easy way to check which drive is mounted is to open "Disk Utility" located in Applications/Utilities/

Good luck with your drive.

[image: Finder prefs]

Comment: This was a perfect answer, extremely well written. Thank you! Solved the problem easily. Unfortunately I cannot upvote yet, but again all my thanks it was driving me nutty.

Comment: You can always upvote me later ;)