# Disk Images no longer show up in Finder's Sidebar

Tags: finder, macos

I've been dealing with an issue for a very long time, I feel like it used to be a problem randomly, but at least for the last few months it's persistent. The Finder no longer lists mounted Disk Images (`.dmg` files) in the sidebar. Not for DMGs, nor external hard drives / external media.

The volumes are listed in Disk Utility, and I have resorted to using that to gracefully unmount the disk image. When a volume is mounted, it is possible to access it by it's `/Volumes/<Volume Name>` path.

[image: Finder, Volume, Finder Preferences, Disk Utility]

In this screenshot you see Finder's Sidebar preferences. You can see that I have a DMG for Clementine open, and Disk Utility confirms that. But the volume isn't showing up on the sidebar. You can also see that the Devices list is expanded, listing my built in volume.

I've done some light searching of options to see if it could be controlled by a plist `defaults` setting, but I haven't found anything yet.

Why aren't mounted volumes showing up on the sidebar? How can I restore them in the list?

This problem began under Mavericks, and has persisted in Yosemite.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/98300/1346 is related, but in their case the devices section of the sidebar was collapsed. The screenshot indicates that is not the case for me.

Comment: the Finder doesn't show the hidden file by default, so you can paste the code to the terminal to confirm `GetFileInfo -av xxx`(you must change xxx to the mount point)

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update.

Just realised that it the **CDS,DVDS,  and iPod** option in the Finder side bar prefs control  showing of DMGs

[image]

You need to check it to get them to show up.

---

The below may be related to External drives not showing up.

---

If you drag them of the sidebar they will never show up even when mounted.

To get them back you need to mount them and drag them back on.

This may not be what is going on with your if this is happening to any new items you have never mounted before. But you could try this and see.

---

Here for illustration a Partition and a DMG being dragged off. 
(But this has happened to me without me realising or for some unknown reason.)

[image]

[image]

---

To get them back I would need to drag them back.

I go to my device window:

[image]

And drag them back to the side bar

[image]

[image]

---

And now they are back.

[image]

Comment: Funny, because disk images are none of CDs, DVDs, or iPods. But they're modeled after CDs enough that it makes sense. I guess. Thanks for figuring this out! Checking that option was enough to get them to show up again.

Comment: I actually found that checking "External Disks" was what made my Disk Image visible in the Sidebar. When I opened Finder preferences, the checkbox for External Disks had a dash in it (presumably reflecting the fact that it was showing an external hard drive in the side bar, but not the Disk Image I was looking for). When I clicked it, the Disk Image showed up in the Sidebar and the dash changed to check mark.

Comment: FWIW, the dash seems to reflect having dragged at least one item of that category out of the sidebar, preventing it—but not other items of its type—from ever showing there again. My favorite setup makes use of this: I start by checking "Hard disks", "External disks", and "CDs, DVDs, and iPods", then drag out the "Macintosh HD" and "Remote CD" items, leaving "Hard disks" and "CDs, DVDs, and iPods" both with dashes. Thus, by default I have no "Devices" section at all in my sidebar, but it shows up whenever I need it (i.e. when I plug something in or mount a disk image).

Answer (score 0):

i am on mojave. 
nothing of the above worked for me.
in order to have the disk images appear in the sidebar when opening a DMG file, i deleted the preferences of finder (~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist) and sidebar (same folder, file com.apple.sidebarlists.plist). 
please note that i had various com.apple.finder.plist files, with the base-name completed by random alphanumeric sequences: com.apple.finder.plist.QNHART6 and the like. i had to delete of all of these com.apple.finder.plist files. after what the behavior was again that when clicking ot oen a DMG file, the disk image appears in the sidebar.